# Looping through string fetched from FirebaseDatabase. How to?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fetching some strings in firebase which are all saved under tag `'imageUID'` and using this imageUIDs to show images.

Here's how I'm fetching it:

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Map<String, String> newRequest = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    imageUID = newRequest.get("imageUID");

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

  }
});
```

This is how I'm using the above fetched `imageUID` to show images:

```
private void doSomethingWithPicasso(String imageUIDh, ImageView target){
        Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                .load(imageUIDh)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_warning_black_24dp)
                .into(target, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error occurred while loading images. Please retry.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

I want to show each every image shown using `imagesUIDs` fetched from database in my app, but what is happening is only the last imageUID is getting used to show images and not all of them.

I was thinking about looping through this string and using each string one by one to show images, but I don't know how to do that! Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: If you `System.out.println(newRequest.get("imageUID"))` in your `onChildAdded()`, you will see that it prints every imageUID. If you're trying to add these items to a view, you'll need to do that inside `onChildAdded()` too.

Comment: I'm trying to show images using these 'imageuids' saved in firebase. The problem is that only the last image is getting shown everytime and not all of them.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show any images. It just sets a variable, which (I suspect) you use elsewhere. You'll need to move that usage *into* `onChildAdded()` to make sure your code deals with all images. Note that you'll get the best help if you share a [complete, minimal example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for replying. Please see the edited question. Isn't my code already in `onChildAdded()`. Please tell me of your talking about something else?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please help me with this too, sir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171064/content-shared-using-dynamic-link-not-getting-displayed-as-same-as-it-was-shared

Answer (score 1):

you may get some help from this try this

```
 firebase.child("key").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot innerDataSanpShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          //DataSnapshot of inner Childerns
          String username = innerDataSnapShot.child("username").getValue().toString();
         } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: how can this help? I mean I have already retrieved the strings from `Firebase`. I just want to show all those retrieved and not just the last one.

Comment: for that i used this to read each element in datasnapshot  for (DataSnapshot innerDataSanpShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {}

Comment: can't this be done in `addChildEventListener()`? or `addValueEventListener()`?

Comment: ERROR: `String username = innerDataSnapShot.child("username").getValue().toString(); not a statement`

Comment: i don't why you getting can you share me your dumy like firebase structure

Comment: what the code you have suggested will do? Please tell me this first.